# Template button not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I've been trying to assign a button to my HTML template, that loads a modal with some further description --- buuuut for some reason I can't actually get the button modifying the css `display:none` to work at all, ever since making it load content dynamically.

The console reports `btn is null` but I have tried `window.onload` as well as `DOMContentLoaded` to no avail. Is this to do with the dynamic loading, and me perhaps needing to assign id's to individual button?

[Codepen here for sake of long code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbYGjW)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've solved your problem. Honestly, you really should not present your question/code like this, its really hard to understand and troubleshoot (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Anyway...
Several problems:

- You're cloning elements, and as such, all the elements are gonna share their attributes (id,name,etc). This is relevant because each one has a different modal box.
- You're trying to access elements (append event Listeners) before such elements have been created. So, your event listeners should be created when you clone each element.
- Your modal box was initialized with "display:block", but you comment that you require it to be hidden in the beggining.

I've changed your code, so each element creates a new id (each modal box as well) and adds an event listener to it.

The most relevant changes are:

```
clone.querySelector(".wineWrapper", "#myBtn").id+=count;
clone.querySelector(".wineWrapper", "#myBtn"+count).onclick=  function(e) {     
     this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
clone.querySelector(".close").onclick=function(){
  this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYojop)

**Note:** I've destroyed your window listener (I thought it might have been the cause of your problem, initially), so if you need it, comment the answer and I'll make an edit.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Still new to SO and presenting my issues concisely. Your answer worked though, thanks for going through it!

Comment: Don't worry! I posted the guidelines so you could improve your next questions (and avoid downvotes on your next questions). I'm glad the answer worked for you! I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: Done! I'll make sure to go through it, still all new to this ^^ Thank you